# Como montar uma consultar para trazer o último valor se baseando em mês e ano?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT DadosFinanceirosFiliado_Valor,
       Filiados_Filiado_Id,
       DadosFinanceirosFiliado_CompetenciaMes,
       DadosFinanceirosFiliado_CompetenciaAno
  FROM dadosfinanceirosfiliado t
 INNER JOIN filiados
    ON dadosfinanceirosfiliado.Filiados_Filiado_Id = filiados.Filiado_Id
 WHERE t.DadosFinanceirosFiliado_Valor(SELECT Filiados_Filiado_Id 
                                         FROM dadosfinanceirosfiliado 
                                        WHERE DadosFinanceirosFiliado_Valor = t.DadosFinanceirosFiliado_Valor 
                                        ORDER BY DadosFinanceirosFiliado_CompetenciaMes, DadosFinanceirosFiliado_CompetenciaAno DESC LIMIT 0, 1)
```

Estou com dificuldade de montar minha consulta, queria saber como montar um *select* pra trazer o último valor de um tabela se baseando em mês e ano (o máximo que eu consegui chegar foi no *sql* mostrado acima).

Tabela aonde a consulta acontece:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: se você usar a função MAX(DadosFinanceirosFiliado_CompetenciaMes) ele busca o último valor data.

Comment: Mas além do mês tem o ano também amigo, como funcionaria melhor tem algum exemplo ??

Comment: Acho que facilitaria se você mostrar algum exemplo das duas tabelas que você vinculou antes. Por qual motivo existe o inner join se você não tem nenhuma condição vinculada a essa tabela?

Comment: pq a coluna Filiados_Filiado_Id vem de outra tabela ela e uma indexação

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que a consulta mostrada na pergunta está correta com relação ao relacionamento entre campos, você pode concatenar ([concat()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp)) ano e mês e fazer uma ordenação decrescente deste resultado (ex *201812*, *201801*), limitando o retorno em um, ou seja, pegando apenas o maior valor; tipo assim:

```
SELECT DadosFinanceirosFiliado_Valor, Filiados_Filiado_Id, DadosFinanceirosFiliado_CompetenciaMes, DadosFinanceirosFiliado_CompetenciaAno
FROM dadosfinanceirosfiliado t
INNER JOIN filiados f ON t.Filiados_Filiado_Id = f.Filiado_Id
ORDER BY CONCAT(DadosFinanceirosFiliado_CompetenciaAno, DadosFinanceirosFiliado_CompetenciaMes) DESC LIMIT 1
```

---

**editado**

conforme comentários, a ideia é trazer o último valor de cada `Filiados_Filiado_Id`; sendo assim, será necessário adicionar uma *subconsulta* para filtragem por filiado. Para isso, será usado o campo de `id` das tabelas (acredito que elas possuam um identificador, você só precisa validar o nome desse campo):

```
SELECT DadosFinanceirosFiliado_Valor, Filiados_Filiado_Id, DadosFinanceirosFiliado_CompetenciaMes, DadosFinanceirosFiliado_CompetenciaAno
FROM dadosfinanceirosfiliado t
INNER JOIN filiados f ON t.Filiados_Filiado_Id = f.Filiado_Id
WHERE f.id in (SELECT f2.id
               FROM filiados f2
               WHERE f2.Filiado_Id = f.Filiado_Id
               ORDER BY CONCAT(DadosFinanceirosFiliado_CompetenciaAno, DadosFinanceirosFiliado_CompetenciaMes) DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Não funcionou ta juntando todos os dados tabela

Comment: @VisionDevelopment, como assim _"todos os dados"_? O _join_ vai juntar tudo mesmo, quem vai dizer o que deve ser exibido ou não é o que vem no _select_. Agora se existe alguma condição de filtragem, tem que ir pra o `where` (nesse caso você precisa especificar pois na pergunta não ficou claro).

Comment: Tipo existe vários Filiados_Filiado_Id, tipo 11 e 12 ai queria o ultimo valor do id 11 e 12 , entendes ?

Comment: no caso é o último pra cada `Filiados_Filiado_Id`?

Comment: isso o ultimo valor de da cada Filiados_Filiado_Id se baseando no mes e ano

Comment: @VisionDevelopment veja se a edição resolve o problema ;)

Comment: deu esse erro Error Code: 1235
This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery', e fora isso eu nao entendi a parte do f2